# Why can't I directly nest a type-selector's rules within a simple class selectors rules?

Tags: css

So as in the question I have:

```
.always-in-header {
  display: grid;
  & > h1 {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

I'm newish to CSS but shouldn't this work? Trying to find how to do this I came to the W3 website which has

```
.foo {
  color: blue;
  & > .bar { color: red; }
}
```

where the only difference is that they don't use a type selector as the nested selector but they're both simple selectors so shouldn't they operate the same in this instance?

edit: for additional context, the error VScode throws is "} expected" for the use of the &

Comment: Is this CSS or SCSS?

Comment: This works fine when the sass is compiled.

Comment: It's just normal, native CSS to my knowledge. I saw in a different website that with SCSS you wouldn't have to use the &, but even on their website it said in native CSS the equivalent code for their SCSS example would be the same syntax that I have without the child operator, but I also tried that and it doesn't work that way either for some reason. the site was https://blog.logrocket.com/native-css-nesting/

Comment: That site is talking about the future. AFAIK nesting is not yet available for CSS in the commonly used browsers as of this moment. See https://caniuse.com/?search=nest (which says it’s available now in Chrome only behind a flag).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a preprocessor language like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), but in any case, the first example should be equivalent to:

```css
.always-in-header {
  display: grid;
}

.always-in-header > h1 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```